# android-how to go back through fragments with webView

Tags: android, android-fragments, webview, fragment-backstack

I'm developing an app in which the user can open as many fragments as he wants, but all fragments are objects of a unique class. the fragment class has only one WebView in its view. everytime the user clicks on a link in the webiew, the links gets loaded in a new fragment. this is how a new fragment is replaced the current fragment:

```
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_holder, PageFragment.newInstance(url)).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

and when the user clicks on back button:

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
```

everything works fine but I'm having some trouble with the situation when the user wants to go back. the point is that when the previous fragment is popped from backstack, again its webview starts to load its url which is not desirable. I want the previous fragment to resume everything: webview state including loaded data, scroll position and etc. how to achieve such behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using replace try adding and in the code replace .replace with .add fragments.That way you can save it's state inside application.

Comment: right, but it will increase memory usage very quickly and after opening let's say 10 fragments, the app will get so slow due to memory leak

Comment: You can remove it when back press from fragments using remove function @Soheil

Comment: @ArchuMohan yes, but imagine the user wants to open 20 fragments. since we are using `add` method, all of them will remain open with their views (before the user press back button and we start to remove them one by one), which is a huge memory consumption.

Comment: This is the only way you can achieve i guess, If you are using single webview for the user , you can append the URL and refresh the webview every time inside the same fragment @Soheil

Comment: @ArchuMohan then I can not have any transition animation between fragments, which I want

Answer (score 0):

You can use a web view to go back. Try this in your back press method

```
if (webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
        }
```

Comment: not desirable! I want each url to open in a new fragment with a transition animation between fragments!

Comment: Create a new WebViewClient and make changes according to your requirement in shouldOverrideUrlLoading() and onPageFinished() methods. Start animation when a user clicks on a link and stop it when page finishes loading.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the problem. the point is that I want the user to be able to see the previous fragment and its content exactly when he clicks back button (I don't want the webview to load the previous url again!)

Answer (score 0):

With 55 fragments it gives no issue with 3 GB ram.so I believe it's practical.

Comment: it absolutely depends on how heavy is the data in each webview! so what you are claiming does not make sense I think!